# How do I move an object on the y axis infinitely

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

[image]

I want to use animations to move this object on the y axis infinitely. Additionally is it possible to add conditions, for example if the object's y axis is past 10 meters than I would want to rotate 30 degrees on the x axis?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, I know how to do animations using keyframes but obviously I can't use that if I want to make the cube move forever along the y axis. I want something that can continuously move the object non-stop.

Comment: Wrong re keyframes. You can [extrapolate an fcurve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/introduction.html#extrapolation) or use a simple driver based on current frame.

Comment: Yeah I could do that but then eventually it would restart all over again as the frames have ended, is there a way to do animations WITHOUT using frames?

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `y` location of the object to a multiple of the current frame should do what you want, the object will always move as long as the time is moving forward:

[image: Example 1]

As for the condition, a simple node tree like this can be used:

[image: Example 2]

If you want a smooth rotation, then using such node tree should work:

[image: Example 3]

You said:

> Yeah I could do that but then eventually it would restart all over again as the frames have ended, is there a way to do animations WITHOUT using frames?

The move node can be used, it will move the object each execution no matter what the condition are, so it won't reset.

[image: Example 4]

Comment: I have a few questions, are you using the "Animations node" addon that you had to get from a third party source?

So using the "move node", allows for the cube to still move even if the animations ended, did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @Jack232 What do you mean by getting AN from a "third party source"? And yes, the move will move the object each execution regardless of the timeline.

Comment: How do you create that specific node tree?

What I meant was since there is an addon called "Animations node" which is not in the Blender's Repository so I had to get it from Github.

I don't know if you have used that addon to create the node trees or not.

Additionally if I were to use the Node Tree as you have used, would it work if I exported it to another game engine?

Comment: @Jack232 Ok, you used the Animation Nodes tag in your question, so I just assumed you wanted to use it. Animation nodes is a procedural system that won't work in any game engine, unless of course you bake the animation you did using that system. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In reality I want to create a walk animation but using frame system, the walking animation restarts when the frames end and I don't want that.

Comment: @Jack232 So it is a character?

Comment: Yes it is a character, may I know what do you mean by _unless of course you bake the animation_. How would I do that? Can you bake the animation in ANY game engine?

Comment: @Jack232 I don't see where the "game engine" come in in your question. Is your question about BGE?